# Too much detail in my scene for viewport to handle even in solid mode

Tags: modeling

My human figure is freckled, very highly detailed and my computer, though very powerful, is slow to respond even in the viewport solid mode. Is there a way to 'Fix," or "solidify" my skin colors etc so its less detail intensive for rendering?

Comment: it depends how you model looks like. Does it have subdivision modifiers? if yes, turn down the number for viewport. If no, you could try it with a decimate modifier. Other question: why is your human figure so much detailed? so you should ask whether the creation of the figure was already the wrong way...every computer (and it might be the fastest on the world) will slow down in Blender if you just add too much vertices to a model. So you should always care about that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Its from a human generator add-on. Not high poly at all. But initial creation its causing slow responses in the viewport. I am new to blender so don't know how else to explain it. It comes rigged but I deleted the rig hoping to improve performance while I altered the appearance of the model.